# issue when appending the RLMArray, update RLMArray in RLMObject and link it with object in swift realm 3.0

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, realm

want some method like which do update the existing followers, and if not exists do add it to DB and link them to user something like

GETS CRASH OVER append in write block, due to duplicate primary key, 
also, it works perfectly if no followers has been added in HKUser Table, once it comes to update it crashes

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
class HKUser: Object{
    dynamic var full_name = ""
    dynamic var email: String?
    dynamic var user_id: String?
    let followers = List<HKUser>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "user_id"
    }
}
```

I want to update the connection of a user in DB also, so I want to do some thing like

```
//1. updated the userFollower array with required data
let userFollowers:[HKUser] = []

//2. now need to link it with my user object and update it in db
if let user = realmWrapper.sharedInstance.getUser(forID: id) {
    try! realm.write {
        //want some method like which do update the existing followers,
        //and if not exists do add it to db and link them to user something like
        //realm.add(user, update: true)

        user.followers.append(contentsOf: followers)
        /**********
         GETS CRASH OVER HERE,
         due to duplicate primary key,
         it works perfect if no followers has been added in HKUser Table,
         once it comes to update it crashes
         **********/
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing, maybe unrelated : why it's your primary key defined as optional ?  You cannot have a nill primary key, right ?

Comment: yes but that not the issue, i have checked that by updating to non optional string

Comment: I'm not really sure about what you want to achieve. But where do you set the primary key? I can see the get function, but not a set. Your error is caused because you are trying to set add a realm object with an existing primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<T>.append()` method save to the Realm implicitly if the objects are unmanaged. That is why the duplicated primary key exception happens.

To avoid this, you can add or update the unmanaged objects before appending to the List. Then you append the objects to the List.

```
try! realm.write {
    ...
    realm.add(followers, update: true) // Add or update the objects first
    user.followers.append(contentsOf: followers)
    ...
}
```

Comment: It should work. Could you make sure passing `followers` to `realm.add(_:update:)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Got same issue, trying to add parsed entity, that was pointing on other unmanaged entities, which had the same value as managed ones.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the case (not enough code in your question to tell) but it looks like you prepare the `userFollowers` array in step 1 to contain ALL the current followers for that specific user.

If this is the case then you'll end up re-adding all the existing followers not only the new ones, hence the duplicate keys.